# iOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError only on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, apple-push-notifications, ios9

I have an app on AppStore.

Download form AppStore in iOS 9(tested with 4 devices), didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken get called, and everything works fine.

And then download from AppStore, iOS 7 (tested with 2 devices), however, when the app calls registerForRemoteNotificationTypes inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError will be invoked, and the error message is

```
Fail To Register For Remote Notifications With Error:
  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment'
  entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x2340a0
  {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string
  found for application}
```

I searched a lot in stackoverflow, most of the answers are about signing with incorrect provisioning file, but if this is the case, why my app works on iOS9?

Lastly, is there some way that I can fix this problem without needing to re-submit my app to AppStore? Thanks.

Comment: What's the deployment target for this app in Xcode? And were there previous versions that might have had a different deployment target?

Comment: Did you select the provisioning profiles for any SDK?

Comment: @Tom Harrington deployment target=6.0, same as previous version.

Comment: @Vasanth yes, I have Build Settings-> Provisioning Profile, 'Debug', 'Distribution', 'Release', all of them set to 'Any iOS SDK' & 'Automatic'.

Comment: I got nothing then. I thought maybe the iOS 7 device was getting an older version that didn't include the push entitlement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems solved!

In Apple Member Center ->  Provisioning Profiles

My provisioning profile's status was invalid, [like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC8hy.png)

I clicked Edit -> check the radio button 'Certificates' -> Generate -> Double clicked the file to import to XCode.

And the push notification works on iOS7 (AdHoc version) now.
Hope it will also work properly when it is on AppStore.

PS: I still don't understand why it previous was working fine on iOS9, but failed on iOS 7.